# How to use htaccess / mod_rewrite for Search Engine Friendly URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed a reciprocal script. In the script install text they have written as follows:

Reciprocal script generates the page of the form

http://www.your-domain.com/myfolder/partners.php?page=x

(where x is a number)

It is possible to use Apache's mod_rewrite to generate search engine friendly pages of the form

Example:  http://www.your-domain.com/myfolder/pagex.html (where x is, again a number).

To do this make sure your hosting company offers mod_rewrite support (almost all linux hostings have it)
and at step 2 above, also modify $urlrewrite = false; to $urlrewrite = true;

Now, I am using a Linuk hosting and Apache Mod-rewrite is enabled by Godaddy hosting. I want to change the following path

/reciprocallinks/partners.php?page=1

to

/reciprocallinks/page1

Can any one please help? What do I have to write in my .htaccess File?

I have already changed the step 2 as directed in the config.php of the script.

I dont know what to write in .htaccess File?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You write this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule reciprocallinks/partners.php reciprocallinks/page%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thnak you for your response. But I get my link something like this <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>

Comment: There was an extra space - try now.